# How to update a .so file with only the newer .o files?

Tags: android, linux, linker, shared-libraries, native

I am working on an Android project that has a native ".so" file embedded in an apk. Whenever we need to release a bug fix we are now releasing a new apk file with ".so" which has the fix. But this is a huge file and is not efficient.

So my question is, is it possible to update the ".so" inside the ".apk" with only the relevant ".o" files that have changed? Meaning keeping the rest of the ".so" file the same, can we just update only those ".o" files that changed? Similar to how some systems push their bug fixes.

Comment: you could potentially distribute binary diff upgrades for the `.so`. Just swapping an `.o` inside an `.so` is not possible because there is more involved than just packing them into a single file. But you probably should not because http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/04/google-bans-self-updating-android-apps-possibly-including-facebooks/

Comment: You cannot modify the installed .apk without replacing it entirely through the install/upgrade mechanism, though you could distribute a supplemental .so file by other means.  Detailed, skillful use of the dynamic linker may allow you to have some native methods override existing ones, but it will be quite tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating parts of dynamic library (`.so`) is not possible. It's not like a static library (`.a`), which is, essentially, just a plain archive with object files. A dynamic library is more like a usual executable and can be thought of as just a program with no `main`. In fact, shared libraries are usually compiled as [PIC](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Hardened/Introduction_to_Position_Independent_Code) and overall, if one part of the library changes, all other parts should be updated.

Say, there's one more instruction in the code of some function `a`, which is followed by functions `b` and `c`. Then addresses of `b` and `c` should be increased by size of the instruction which got added to `a`. Then all call sites of `b` and `c` inside this dynamic library should be updated with new addresses.

That said, it could be done in theory, but the cost of implementation is much higher than profit from it.